# Почему не обновляется Label

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть label, который в качестве контекста содержит объект Point. При изменении значения этого объекта label не обновляется. Как исправить.

```
internal class Point
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{x}, {y}";
    }
}

internal static class PointManager
{
    public static Point Point => new Point(0,0);
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        PointManager.Point.X = 1;
        //как сделать, чтобы на экране отобразилось 1,0
    }
}
```

часть XAML:

```
   <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10" Margin="3" Padding="10" Background="SandyBrown">
         <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Binding Source="{x:Static local:PointManager.Point}"  />
         </Label>
   </Border>
```

Comment: `Label` в WPF это `ContentControl` и для простых текстов его не нужно использовать (как в WinForms), для этого есть легковесный `TextBlock`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде несколько проблем, во-первых, этот код:

```
public static Point Point => new Point(0,0);
```

при каждом обращении создает новый экземпляр, надо переписать так:

```
public static Point Point { get; } = new Point(0,0);
```

Во-вторых, привязка нормально работает только со свойствами, вы же надеетесь на неявный вызов `ToString()` поэтому первое что надо сделать, это или добавить в класс `Point` еще одно свойство:

```
public string Value => $"{x}, {y}";
```

и привязаться непосредственно к нему:

```
<Binding Source="{x:Static local:PointManager.Point}" Path="Value" />
```

Либо, что более правильно т.к. модель не должна подстраиваться под представление, привязаться к уже имеющимся *свойствам* (напишите вместо `Label`):

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Run Text="{Binding X, Source={x:Static local:PointManager.Point}}"/>,
    <Run Text="{Binding Y, Source={x:Static local:PointManager.Point}}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

В-третьих, ваше представление никак не может догадаться, что данные изменились и их пора перечитать, поэтому либо надо сказать привязке чтобы она обновила свою цель, например, так:

```
<!--Добавил Name-->
<Run Name="MyText" Text="{Binding X, Source={x:Static local:PointManager.Point}}"/>,
```

и в методе:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    PointManager.Point.X = 1;
    MyText.GetBindingExpression(Run.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
}
```

Либо, что более правильно, ваши классы, к которым вы выполняете привязки (это будет VM слой уже, а не модель – почитайте про паттерн MVVM), должны оповещать об изменениях свойств. Для этого в стандартной библиотеке существует интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`, с которым прекрасно работает WPF.

Обычно реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged` выглядит примерно так:

```
abstract class Vm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;
        field = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Тогда, ваш класс превращается в такой:

```
internal class Point : Vm
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int X { get => x; set { Set(ref x, value); } }
    public int Y { get => y; set { Set(ref y, value); } }
}
```

Всё, привязка получит оповещение `PropertyChanged` и обновится самостоятельно, без явного ей на то указания.

Comment: Андрей, все равно не обновляется, ни через MyText.GetBindingExpression(Run.TextProperty).UpdateTarget(),  ни через INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: У меня значение PointManager.Point.X  не меняется и при каждом повторном нажатии равняется 0.

Comment: все нашла проблему, спасибо большое!

Comment: `PointManager.Point.X` не меняется, потому что он при каждом обращении создает и возвращает **новый** экземпляр. Надо заменить на `public static Point Point { get; } = new Point(0,0);` Забыл об этом написать в ответе сразу.